# Search API Index fields getting unselected

Tags: search

I am using Search API to define search pages and facets and I connect to a Solr engine. My search has been working perfectly until recently, after my last documents have been indexed. Now, every so often, two of my full-text fields on the "Fields" tab of the index configuration page just become unselected. Both fields are long text. This happens at least once a day. I then get no search results back and I have to go to the index's field selection tab (`admin/config/search/search_api/index/my_search/fields`), select them again, and click "Save". The search results are then available immediately (i.e. it doesn't have to re-index first).

What is also worrying (actually more worrying), is that sometimes when this happens, the fields aren't even available to be selected AT ALL! When this happens, I have to clean the index completely using drush and then they become available again. Then I have to re-index all of my documents (about 8 million), which takes a whole day.

This site is live, so I am desperate. Please help!

Comment: Doesn't anybody have a clue about this?

Comment: Does the site use Features?

Comment: Hi Alfred. Yes, it does (initially posted no, but after checking - yes it does). We don't update the features though. There are 2 features: one defining some fields and content types, and the other defining views.

Comment: Update: We've cloned our production environment and the cloned environment is not giving this problem. I am stumped...

Comment: And now the cloned environment started doing it as well. At least I can use the test environment to try things.